# remove server.log.yyyy-mm-dd older than 30 days jboss eap 6.2 standalone

Tags: java, backup, jboss-eap-6

I need some help in order to clear older than 30 days logs from /standalone/log in jboss-eap-6.2.
I tried editing the /standalone/configuration/standalone-full-ha.xml, by adding max-backup-index=30 to the periodic-rotating-file-handler to no extent.

any thoughts would be appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you can create a cron task, this command should help:

```
find /path/to/logs -name "*.log" -type f -ctime 30 -delete
```

Comment: i know i could use cron, but i was wondering if there is any way of  doing this within jboss itself.

Comment: Nope you have to use a cron job or some kind of scheduled job.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to address this; the problem was in our configuration...instead of using standalone.xml, the configuration was stored in standalone-full-ha.xml.
in the same time, i removed

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
   <formatter>
       <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
   </formatter>
   <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
   <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
```